# Strange problem with l2tp / ipsec vpn

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, vpn, ipsec

fresh install with ubuntu 18.04.1 here.

I followed this link in order to setup a vpn connection at my workplace
https://blog.bvzzdesign.com/2018/06/18/easily-connect-to-l2p-ipsec-vpn-in-ubunutu-18-04/

I have set up my vpn connection and i have successfully connected at my workplace.

the guide mentions to stop the xl2tpd service, i followed these commands sudo service xl2tpd stop
sudo systemctl disable xl2tpd
but i could connect at my workplace even without disabled the xl2tpd service. I didn't understand why i have to stop the specific service. I can connect normally with and without xl2tpd.

The problem is after i close the vpn connection, i don't have internet access(specifically i have internet, i can ping 8.8.8.8 for example, it looks like more a dns issue.)

In order to get that fixed i have to disable and re enable the wifi. Can someone help me why is that happening? My vpn ipv4 settings are dhcp and my normal wifi connection is dhcp too.

thanks!

-- edit : after upgrading at ubuntu 18.10 the same problem/bug still exists. I can't access any webpage after i disconect from a vpn until i turn off and on again the wifi.

Comment: anyone with the problem above?

Comment: have anyone experienced this problem? after upgrade at ubuntu 18.10 i have the same results, after i disconnect from the l2tp vpn, i cant access any webpage until i turn off and on the wifi or disconnect and connect again at my ssid.

Comment: I believe it is an issue with KDE's plasma nm package, see following page for a workaround https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048392/resolv-conf-permissions-ownership-change-after-vpn-disconnect and some other details here https://github.com/nm-l2tp/network-manager-l2tp/issues/95

Comment: thank you very much for the info! That is exactly the problem i am facing. Very strange bug although.

Comment: well i added the script provided from the links at /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d  but nothing actually happens. I restarted the pc, connected and disconnected from a vpn connection but the dns issue still remains. Am i doing something wrong with the script? it has root ownership the script. I tried running it manually and still the same problem with the vpn, nothing changes.

Comment: After disconnecting the VPN, what is the output of `ls -l /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` ? Did you make the script executable, e.g. do something like  `chmod a+rx /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/*.sh` ?

Comment: you made my day! worked like a charm! it needed just a chmod, how dumb am i to miss it.